# Фейл при регистрации broadcast'a в манифесте

Tags: android, java

Регистрация `broadcast`'a в манифесте закончилась фейлом. а конкретно: захотел я прикрутить в свой манифест `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`. прикрутил, фильтр прописал, запустил программу на своём телефоне. отключаю/включаю наушники на своём телефоне и ничего не происходит. Пошёл другим путём и прописал `broadcastReceiver` как внутренний класс в своей `Activity`. прикрутил методом `registerBroadcast` и всё заработало. Сразу появилась реакция на наушники. На `stackoverflow` вроде как (а английским пока не особо) нашёл инфо что не все `Broadcast`'ы будут работать если их прикручивать в манифесте и посоветовали использовать регистрацию `Broadcasta` в программном коде.

Так вот:

1. Как узнать конкретный список какие `Intent.Action` можно использовать в манифесте, а какие нет?
2. Может быть для всех поголовно использовать регистрацию в программном коде?

Comment: Может стоит перестать "прикручивать" и почитать документацию? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html  также может помоч http://habrahabr.ru/post/149875/

Comment: @jimpanzer не стоит минусовать такие вопросы - чел по делу спрашивает

Comment: в той ссылке на хабре есть один комментарий, в котором сказано что некоторые Intent.Action не могут быть зарегестированы в Manifest. К сожалению в самой документации я этого не нашёл. Будет ли ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG работать с манифестом или нет в комментариях не написано. Вот поэтому я и спрашиваю:

"Kакие конкретно Intent.Action работают с манифестом а какие нет?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На те **intent**-ы, которые не получается отловить в **manifest**-e, система навесила flag **`FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY`**. Обычно это такие intent-ы, которые нет смысла ловить, если программа не запущена. Это события о выключении экрана, перехода телефона в спящий режим и подобные. В вашем случае - подключение наушников. Списка таких событий нет, но [поиском](https://www.google.ru/search?q=OS+set+the+flag+%22Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY%22&oq=OS+set+the+flag+%22Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.463j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY)%3B&safe=off)
можно найти некоторые из них.
Например:

```
ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED  
ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED

ACTION_SCREEN_ON  
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

ACTION_USB_ANLG_HEADSET_PLUG  
ACTION_USB_DGTL_HEADSET_PLUG  
ACTION_HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG  
ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
```

Выход: логически думать, могла ОС поставить на конкретный интент флаг **`FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY`**.